# codemagicでのビルドでFirebase App Distributionの公開がスキップされる。

Tags: flutter

私はflutterアプリをcodemagicで自動ビルドし、Firebase App Distributionを利用してテスターに配布したいのですが、公開がうまくいっておらず悩んでいます。
codemagicの設定でDistributionの欄からFirebase App Distributionは正しく設定してあります。
こちらがPublishing欄のコマンドラインです。

```
== Gathering artifacts ==

== Publishing artifacts ==

Publishing artifact app-release.aab
Publishing artifact mapping.txt
Publishing artifact Runner.app.zip
Skip publishing Ios to Firebase App Distribution: no matching artefacts found.
Skip publishing to Firebase App Distribution: no matching artefacts found.
Skip publishing Android to Firebase App Distribution: no matching artefacts found.
Skip publishing to Firebase App Distribution: no matching artefacts found.
```

android,iosどちらもエラーなく完了しています。
この問題を解決させる方法をご存じの方教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribution欄にて、Android code signing及び、iOS code signingの項目も有効にする必要があるかと思います。